# useQuery after server-side rendering

Tags: javascript, apollo, next.js, react-apollo, apollo-client

I'm using `next.js` and apollo with react hooks.

For one page, I am server-side rendering the first X "posts" like so:

```
// pages/topic.js

const Page = ({ posts }) => <TopicPage posts={posts} />;

Page.getInitialProps = async (context) => {
    const { apolloClient } = context;
    const posts = await apolloClient.query(whatever);

    return { posts };
};

export default Page;
```

And then in the component I want to use the `useQuery` hook:

```
// components/TopicPage.js

import { useQuery } from '@apollo/react-hooks';

export default ({ posts }) => {
    const { loading, error, data, fetchMore } = useQuery(whatever);

    // go on to render posts and/or data, and i have a button that does fetchMore
};
```

Note that the `useQuery` here executes essentially the same query as the one I did server-side to get posts for the topic.

The problem here is that in the component, I already have the first batch of posts passed in from the server, so I don't actually want to fetch that first batch of posts again, but I do still want to support the functionality of a user clicking a button to load more posts.

I considered the option of calling `useQuery` here so that it starts at the second "page" of posts with its query, but I don't actually want that. I want the topic page to be fully loaded with the posts that I want (i.e. the posts that come from the server) as soon as the page loads.

Is it possible to make `useQuery` work in this situation? Or do I need to eschew it for some custom logic around manual query calls to the apollo client (from `useApolloClient`)?

Comment: You should be using `getDataFromTree` to initialize your store based on the queries that are initially rendered in your app as shown [here](https://github.com/adamsoffer/next-apollo-example). `fetchMore` should then work as expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out this was just a misunderstanding on my part of how server side rendering with nextjs works. It does a full render of the React tree before sending the resulting html to the client. Thus, there is no need to do the "first" `useQuery` call in `getInitialProps` or anything of the sort. It can just be used in the component alone and everything will work fine as long as `getDataFromTree` is being utilized properly in the server side configuration.

Comment: I am trying to figure this out too, I see that when I console log after using `useQuery` it will console in the server that it's loading/fetching the data but then it will not wait for it to finish fetching nor it will console log again the data that it fetched, instead, the client side console logs that it's also loading/fetching which makes me think it is doing a double fetch?